# validating password with uppercase and lowercase

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my password textbox aspx elements:

```
<label for="password">Password</label>
<asp:Text Box ID="User Password" runat ="server"  Text Mode ="Password" ></asp:Text Box>
```

This is my code behind

```
protected void LoginSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BOL ObjectBOL = new BOL();
    BAL ObjectBAL = new BAL();
    ObjectBOL.UserName_value = UserText.Text;
    ObjectBOL.UserPassword_value = UserPassword.Text;

    try
    {

        String Login = ObjectBAL.LoginBAL(ObjectBOL);
        int i = int.Parse(Login);
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("dashboard.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {
            //UserText.Text = "";
            //UserPassword.Text = "";
            lblMsg.Text = (" Login Failed.... Try Again...");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception LoginException)
    {
        throw LoginException;
    }
    finally
    {
        ObjectBAL = null;
    }
}
```

When the user enters the password in upper case or lower case letters it was accepting the value and redirecting to the next page.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select  count (*) from UserTable where User_Name='" + Login.UserName_value +
                    "'and User_Password='" + Login.UserPassword_value + "'", con);
                string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                return str;
```

Comment: Please state clearly what your question is. What _specifically_ is happening, and how is this different from what you want to happen?

Comment: For Example :If my password was in lowercase (admin) it should accept the exact lower case value .....it should not accept the uppercase values (ADMIN) or (Admin) ...

Comment: Actually your problem is not clear , if u are looking for any case comparison u can use String.Compare or String.Equals methods

Comment: @ShamilKhan: when provided details requested in the comments, please put those details in the question itself, not in the comments. As far as the specifics go: where is the code that actually does that validation? All I see is a call to `ObjectBAL.LoginBAL()` which then returns an integer formatted as a string. Presumably something happens in the call where the password is validated, but you haven't shown that code.

Comment: Sory dude.. Im new to .NET.. Actually I didnt  did any validation in password  for accepting values.. Tht oly im asking is thr any javascript for password while accepting values

Comment: show the code of the `LoginBal`. by this code no one can help you.

Comment: Where did u use  return str; ?? can u please include LoginBal()code

Comment: This is my Loginbal()                                                         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select  count (*) from UserTable where User_Name='" + Login.UserName_value +
                    "'and User_Password='" + Login.UserPassword_value + "'", con);
                string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                return str;

Comment: @ShamilKhan you should use edit question for update in code not the comment.anyways what databse you are using?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Username = `test'; delete usertable --`.

Comment: @ShamilKhan your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select COUNT(*) from UserTable where (CAST(User_Name as varbinary(50))=cast('"+ Login.UserName_value+"' as varbinary))  and (CAST(User_Password as varbinary(50))=cast('"+Login.UserPassword_value+"' as varbinary)),con);
con.Open();
string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
con.Close();
return str;
```

try this this will work

Answer (score 2):

There are two solution for this problem

1. Change your database table nature .By default SQL server do the case insensitive comparison you need to alter your db table.

   ALTER TABLE UserTable 
   ALTER COLUMN User_Password VARCHAR(20)
   COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS

Or you can append  **COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS** to every query at last without altering your table.

> Latin1_General_CS_AS is for case sensitive and Latin1_General_CI_AS for case insensitive comparison

[how to make case sensitive comparison in SQL Server](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/)

2. Or you can convert your password in  binary then store in db and compare binary content from db and user entered password.

***Suggestion***

1. You can **go with first solution** it will take less time. but second solution is more secure then first one. Do read about this on google. you will find the cons of the directly storing password in plain text.
2. As mentioned in comment your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Use **parametrize query** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Update your SQL Command query with `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` as mentioned below to compare string with case sensitive:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select  count (*) from UserTable where User_Name='" + Login.UserName_value +
                    "' and User_Password='" + Login.UserPassword_value + "' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS", con);
string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
return str;
```

Answer (score 1):

So I see a couple issues here that you should really look at, let me address those then I'll help with the question you asked.

First, as mentioned in the comments by @Erik Philips, you should be using parameterized queries rather than string concatenation.

Second, you really should be hashing your passwords using a strong hashing algorithm, so if/when your DB gets compromised, you don't divulge all your user's passwords to the attacker.

Ok, as for the actual question at hand you have two options.  The far more common solution I've seen is to do the Select just based on the user name, then compare the *hashed* passwords in C# code to determine whether the user should be logged in or not.

The other option would be to use a case sensitive query in SQL, which in SQL Server requires you to assign a collation via the `COLLATE` command (either to the query or to the column), perhaps assigning it to whichever relevant character set you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `sql` query only. no need to change table nature and anything else.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("select count(*) from UserTable where User_Name COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS ='" + Login.UserName_value + "'and User_Password COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS ='" + Login.UserPassword_value + "'", con);
con.Open();
string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
con.Close();
return str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link, I think as mentioned above collate is the way to go about.

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/case-sensitive-search-fetching-lowercase-or-uppercase-string